# Maping/filtering object keys from an object to a new object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, variables

I have an object called `revenue`:

```
var revenue = {
    "Month": "2011-01",
    "Week1_Revenue": "123.02",
    "week2_Revenue": "330.51",
    "Week3_Reenue": "201.98",
    "Month1_TotalRevenue": "700.12"
};
```

I want to filter and/or map some attributes to a new object:

```
var filtered = {
    "Month": "2011-01",
    "Week1_Revenue": "123.02",
    "Month1_TotalRevenue": "700.12"
};
```

I want to specifically filter `Month`, `Week1_Revenue` and `Month1_TotalRevenue`.

I attempted something but it tells me that `.map` is not a function. Originally, the object was a string so I called `JSON.parse()` on it:

```
var revenueMod = revenue.map(item => {
    return {
        "date": item['Month'],
        "w1_revenue": item['Week1_Revenue'],
        "total_revenue": item['Month1_Revenue']
    };
});
```

Comment: `"Month"="2011-01"` just to clarify, is this a typo meant to be `"Month":"2011-01"`?

Comment: Yeah thats what I meant,but i fixed it

Comment: `map` is an array method and `revenue` is an object. Please reads the documentation for more info.

Comment: `.map()` is not a function here because `revenue` is not an array, it's an object. You'll have to wrap the object in `[]` (preferred) but if you have no control over the object, just test it to see if it's an array, and if not, directly access with `revenue["Month"]` etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is an array method and `revenue` is an object here. You can simply get the new object like:

```js
var revenue = { "Month": "2011-01", "Week1_Revenue": "123.02", "week2_Revenue": "330.51", "Week3_Reenue": "201.98", "Month1_TotalRevenue": "700.12"};

var filtered = {
  'Month': revenue['Month'],
  'Week1_Revenue': revenue['Week1_Revenue'],
  'Month1_TotalRevenue': revenue['Month1_TotalRevenue']
};

console.log( filtered )
```

Comment: At the risk of being pedantic, there is no need for the `Object.assign` call here as its second argument is already a new object.

Comment: So I tried this, and It gave me undefined on my side, since originally before this array was created, I parsed it since it was a string array.

Comment: and is the `revenue` in this demo same as what you get after using `JSON.parse()` on the string response?

Comment: The demo is working, but on my side It's giving me undefined.

Comment: OK. I think I know why I'm getting undefined on my side.

Comment: I fixed it, It was still a string when I do one JSON.parse so I did another JSON.parse, and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Map is indeed not a function, because revenue is not an array - it's an object.

Would this be what you're trying to do?

```
var revenueMod = {
  date: revenue['Month'],
  w1_revenue: revenue['Week1_Revenue'],
  total_revenue: revenue['Month1_Revenue']
}
```

Just leave the map function out altogether.